# How can I restore flutter built in widgets?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use Future.delayed in my flutter app but cannot use the Delayed class because I guess at some point I messed up 'Duration' by entering into it.

```
Duration fastestMarathon = new Duration(hours:2, minutes:3, seconds:2);
```

This line of code should not throw up errors but it does in my IDE saying that the class does not exist.[image: this is what I get]

Any idea on how to go back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Maybe there is another way but I ran flutter upgrade in the terminal and it brought back the built in widgets.
Also if my dear downvoter could leave me a reason, I could perhaps improve in the future.